# Material Design 3 Carousel

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement the Carousel component from Material Design 3. I've tried to follow the guide from Github docs on how to implement Material Design 3, but when I try to implement the Carousel component I get this error:
`Class referenced in the layout file, com.google.android.material.carousel.MaskableFrameLayout, was not found in the project or the libraries`

I have these dependencies:
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'` in build.gradle (module)

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

and
`compileSdk 33`

in build.gradle (module)

Comment: are you sure that MaskableFrameLayout is a component inside the material library? It seems to be a different library: implementation 'com.github.christophesmet:android_maskable_layout:v1.3.1'

Comment: The class reference is something I got from the Material Design's Github documentation on how to implement Carousel.
Link: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Carousel.md

Comment: ok, the carousel component is available from material version 1.9.0. I don't know why the documentation say to use the 1.5.0 version

Comment: Try using `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0-alpha01'`